# Camel simple expression is not evaluated between runs

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a Camel 2.18.2 app running using a quartz cron statement, every day at 4AM.

My route collects from SQL as payload to my routes and then stores the current date, yesterdays date and tomorrows date as headers and calls a velocity endpoint to generate a file with these dates and the payload.

As far as I can see the file gets populated with new values every day **but** the dates are not evaluated, they are the same as from first run.

How can I accomplish the dates are evaluated on each run?

```
from("{{camm.quartz}}")
            .routeId("CAM")
            .autoStartup("{{camm.startup}}")
            .log("Consuming positions view")
            .to(fromStr)
            .bean((Processor) exchange -> {
                final List<Map<String, Object>> body = exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
                List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Map<String, Object> row : body) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : row.entrySet()) {
                        myList.add((String) entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
                exchange.getOut().setBody(myList);
            })
            .multicast()
            .stopOnException()
            .parallelProcessing()
            .to("direct:a", "direct:b")
            .end();

//First we create all actions
from("direct:a")
        .routeId("Creating CAMM Request file")
        .autoStartup("{{camm.startup}}")
        .setHeader("replyFileName", constant("{{camm.bloomberg.response.file}}"))
        .setHeader("dateFrom", simple(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).format(formatter)))
        .setHeader("dateTo", simple(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).format(formatter)))
        .setHeader("actionsDate", constant("effective"))
        .to("velocity:velocity/cam/camm.vm?contentCache=false")
        .to("{{camm.bloomberg.outgoing}}?fileName={{camm.bloomberg.request.file}}")
        .log("Bloomberg Request File: {{camm.bloomberg.response.file}} created")
        .end();


//create updates
from("direct:b")
        .routeId("Creating CAMM Updates file")
        .autoStartup("{{camm.startup}}")
        .setHeader("replyFileName", constant("{{camm.bloomberg.response.file.updates}}"))
        .setHeader("dateFrom", simple(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1).format(formatter)))
        .setHeader("dateTo", simple(LocalDate.now().format(formatter)))
        .setHeader("actionsDate", constant("entry"))
        .to("velocity:velocity/cam/camm.vm?contentCache=false")
        .to("{{camm.bloomberg.outgoing}}?fileName={{camm.bloomberg.request.file.updates}}")
        .log("Bloomberg Updates File: {{camm.bloomberg.response.file.updates}} created")
        .end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected because the Camel route is setup once, so the code above is only executed once to setup the routes.

So the code with LocalDate now etc should be either moved to a method and use a method call instead of simple.

Or use the simple date function where you can add or move days with plus and minus `date:now+24h:yyyMMdd`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.